# tikz externalization and renewindex

Tags: indexing, tikz-external

I have a bizarre problem with the `langscibook` class it calls renewindex and this call breks the externalization functionality of `tikz` (`forest`).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{index}

\AtBeginDocument{
\makeindex
\renewindex{default}{adx}{and}{lsNameIndexTitle}
}




\usepackage[external]{forest}
% All externalized graphics go go the \externaldirectory
\tikzexternalize[prefix=external-figures/]
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centerline{
\begin{forest}
[V
  [NP [er] ]
  [V
    [NP
      [Det [das] ]
      [N [Buch] ] ]
    [V
      [NP
        [Det [dem] ]
        [N [Mann] ] ]
      [V [gibt] ] ] ] ]
\end{forest}
}
\end{figure}%


\end{document}
```

If you uncomment the `\renewindex` line, everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see it works if you remove your `\AtBeginDocument{...}` around the makeindex code. The problem you face is namely an undefined index called "default". From the log file of an externalized figure:

```
! LaTeX Error: Index type `default' not defined.
```

`\makeindex` defines this index type default. But tikz does not take care of it since you do it at the begin of your document.

If you really need to do this as late as possible consider using the `etoolbox` package and switching to:

```
\AtEndPreamble{
    \makeindex
    \renewindex{default}{adx}{and}{lsNameIndexTitle}
    \tikzexternalize[prefix=external-figures/]
}
```

Your MWE (compilable and working) would look like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{index}

\AtEndPreamble{
    \makeindex
    \renewindex{default}{adx}{and}{lsNameIndexTitle}
    \tikzexternalize[prefix=external-figures/]
}

\usepackage[external]{forest}
% All externalized graphics go go the \externaldirectory
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centerline{
\begin{forest}
[V
  [NP [er] ]
  [V
    [NP
      [Det [das] ]
      [N [Buch] ] ]
    [V
      [NP
        [Det [dem] ]
        [N [Mann] ] ]
      [V [gibt] ] ] ] ]
\end{forest}
}
\end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`\tikzexternalize` executes LaTeX's `\nofiles` to suppress generation of auxiliary files as "generation of these files is not thread-safe" [pgfcoreexternal.code.tex] and `\nofiles` does `\let\makeindex\relax` and `\let\makeglossary\relax`.

Thus, executing `\tikzexternalize` after loading `index.sty` but before executing `\makeindex` will fail. (As explained [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352160/16819), index `default` will never get defined and so it will be an error to redefine it.) The OP's example falls in this category as `\tikzexternalize` is executed after loading `index.sty` and `\makeindex` is executed at the beginning of the document. The two solutions proposed in the abovementioned answer obviously avoid the undesired situation.

It is also possible to solve the problem without changing the order in which stuff is loaded/executed.  This might be handy sometimes:

```
\let\origmakeindex\makeindex
\tikzexternalize[prefix=external-figures/]
\let\makeindex\origmakeindex
```

By the way, the authors of PGF were aware that executing `\nofiles` might cause problems for some documents. PGF safeguards against a conflict with `glossary.sty`, which `\renewcommand`s `\makeglossary` (and obviously fails if `\makeglossary` was `\let` to `\relax`), but the safeguard mechanism unfortunately doesn't automatically cover `index.sty`.

Another detail: an even more minimal (non-working) example, which uses neither `scrbook` nor `forest`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\usepackage{index}
\AtBeginDocument{
\makeindex
\renewindex{default}{adx}{and}{lsNameIndexTitle}
}

\tikzexternalize[prefix=external-figures/]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```